# what datatype to choose when using blobs in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I understand that Postgresql has a bytea datatype and I have used it before. But I want to use the "blob" datatype so the data does not get loaded into memory first. However I don't see a blog data type in Pgadmin. Do I use the "oid" data type instead?

Comment: [Large Objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html)

Comment: Which are covered in detail here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/largeobjects.html